# How to check if an element is a subclass of element in a lists of classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I want to return `true` if the argument is an instance of a class in the list. Here's my snippet:

```
private Class[] classes;

public boolean belongsToList(Object obj){
  return Arrays.asList(classes).contains(obj.getClass());
}
```

but when the classes list contains the *superclass* of obj class and not the exact child class itself, this code returns false.

How do I make it return `true` for instances of a *subclass* of an element in `classes`?

Comment: i don't need .getSuperclass() because that wouldn't work with the chid classes in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stream of `classes` with a predicate based on `Class#isInstance()`:

```
public boolean belongsToList(Object obj) {
    return Arrays.stream(classes).filter(c -> c.isInstance(obj)).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

Internally, processing halts/returns at the first match, so this is efficient.

Comment: will this run on java 7 and 6 as well?

Comment: @andreadoli no. this requires java 8 (which has been out for nearly 2 years now)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without iterating the array of classes somehow (with a classic loop or Java 8 stream). You chould do this way:

```
public static boolean belongsToList(Class<?> obj){
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or in the case you need to know if obj is a class instance:

```
public static boolean belongsToList(Object obj){
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [instanceof](http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator) operator instead

```
boolean belongsToList(Object my_obj) {
   for (Object o : classes) {
       if (my_obj instanceof o) 
           return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```